# Submit button outside form_for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, form-for

I have set up some horizontal tabs using twitter bootstrap and I am rendering a form inside each of the tabs:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
      <%= render :partial => "shipdr/websites/form", locals: {:@shipdr_website => shipdr_website} %>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
    Another form (not yet implemented)
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
    Another form (not yet implemented).
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in shipdr/websites/form I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shipdr_website) do |f| %>
  <% if @shipdr_website.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@shipdr_website.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shipdr_website from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @shipdr_website.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :api_key %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to move the submit button outside of the "tab-content" area so when a user clicks the submit button, all three forms area submitted. All forms will use that same model and the same action but will have different field. The idea is similar to a wizard except I am using tabs.

Does anyone have any idea how I can move the submit button outside of the form_for loop and how I can submit the three forms with a single button?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can submit 3 forms at a time. But you can do this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <%= simple_form_for(@shipdr_website) do |f| %>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
      <%= render :partial => "shipdr/websites/form", locals => {:f => f, :shipdr_website => @shipdr_website} %>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
      Another form (not yet implemented)
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
      Another form (not yet implemented).
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And remove that from your partials, leaving just the inputs.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shipdr_website) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this. It seems to be working when I move the form out of the partial. However, when I call the partial as you describe I am getting an undefined variable error for 'f'. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I edited the answer. Some bad formatted code in the render :partial.

Comment: I'm also using a similar system with a big form spreading over multiple tabs. However, one "big" form has some disadvantages. In some tabs, you might want to be able to insert some form-unrelated content, or some button_to for another POST path. Spawning modals and transferring data via data-attributes is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of doing that is with Javascript: you can move the button and send 3 forms at a time via Ajax. If you use Jquery you can use http://jquery.malsup.com/form