# How to use scaffolding and form_for in RoR with Mustache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, mustache, scaffolding, form-for

I'm using mustache templates in my rails app with [mustache-rails](https://github.com/josh/mustache-rails)
. I wanted to do scaffolding and use the form_for helper, but I can't get the submit button working. I found this https://gist.github.com/954994 , but I don't want to do it so generic. I just wanted to turn a my scaffolding to a template based version.

this is my view class

```
module Views
  module Slideshows
    class New < Layouts::Application

       def form
         form_for(@slideshow) do |f|
          {
              :submit => f.submit
          }
         end
       end

       def errors?
           @slideshow.errors.any?
       end

       def error_header
           "#{pluralize(@slideshow.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post from being saved:"
       end

       def errors
         @slideshow.errors.full_messages
       end

       def back_link
         link_to 'Back', slideshows_path
       end  

    end
  end
end
```

this is my template class

```
<h1>New slideshow</h1>

{{#form}}
  {{#errors?}}
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>{{error_header}}</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
      {{#errors}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
      {{/errors}}
    </ul>
  {{/errors?}}
  <div class="actions">
    {{submit}}
  </div>
{{/form}}

{{back_link}}
```

In my opinion the problem is I cant access :submit in the form_for block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit button outside form\_for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147435/submit-button-outside-form-for-loop)